# Run console command background after login Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, process, controller, listener

I want to run a custom symfony2 console command background after login. I make a listener and try to use the process to run the command at background but the function not work well.
Here is my code

```
class LoginListener
{
    protected $doctrine;
    private $RecommendJobService;
    public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if($user)
        {
        $process = new Process('ls -lsa');
        $process->start(function ($type, $buffer) {
                $command = $this->RecommendJobService;
                $input = new ArgvInput();
                $output = new ConsoleOutput();
                $command->execute($input, $output);
                echo "1";

        });
        }
    }
    public function setRecommendJobService($RecommendJobService) {
      $this->RecommendJobService = $RecommendJobService;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Thx for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the function not work well"* ? Anything happens? Errors?

Comment: Nothing happens. the start()function doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any variables that you need to access from inside your anonymous function you have to use a `use` statement. Further $this could conflict due to scope.

```
$that = $this;
$process->start(function ($type, $buffer) use ($that) {
    $command = $that->RecommendJobService;
    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $command->execute($input, $output);
    echo "1";
});
```

Also you can take your anonymous function and test it outside of the start() method like this.

```
$closure = function ($type, $buffer) use ($that) {
    $command = $that->RecommendJobService;
    $input = new ArgvInput();
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();
    $command->execute($input, $output);
    echo "1";
};
$closure();
```

Then you can put some debugging in there and see if it runs. I'm not sure if echo is a good way to deal with the console. I would recommend Monolog or the `$output->writeln($text);` command.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. The code inside the function could work. I think the problem is the process->start doesn't work. Because I put a logger inside the function, it won't be shown on the log. When I change start with run() function, everything works well. But I have to wait for the process done rather than make it work in background. Thx @Flip

Comment: I checked the `start()` method, it should take a callback. But the manual puts the callback in the `run()` method. Try this instead: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously

Comment: Thank you. That's help me a lot.